# HTML 5 Native form validation callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap

Ive got a table that contains a series of dynamic form fields and im using html5 and bootstrap 3 to control my site.

Ive decided as its only going to be me using this app that i can use native html 5 form validation.

What im wondering is, how do i detect if there is a validation error anywhere on my form and if so, control additional actions that are performed by the form?

The reason i ask, is because im validating dynamic fields and setting some to be disabled, but then enabling them on submit, and if i do so the validation routine catches it and i cant re-disable them when i need to

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Valdiations are already well defined in bootstrap only. You simply have to add the class for a specfic validation like email and the alerts would appear itself (if entered incorrect format) on rumtime ,say submission of form. You can try using those classes . Hope it helps

Comment: He's talking about clientside HTML5 validation. Bootstrap handles styling for serverside validation.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that HTML5 is no longer just HTML, but instead a bunch of technologies lumped under that banner, I figured there would probably be javascript hooks for the validation.

Take a gander at this information from Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#The_HTML5_constraint_validation_API

It looks like you will have no problem hooking into the validation, and doing what you need.